# with cdn works fine, but with nodejs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to use `makerjs` with node.js but it doesn't work.
If I use cdn like bellow,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/makerjs@0/target/js/browser.maker.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bezier-js@2/bezier.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/opentype.js@0/dist/opentype.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works well.

If I look at the documentation, it says 
`npm install makerjs --save`
and put this in javascript

```
var makerjs = require('makerjs');
```

So I made my html like bellow after installing makerjs with `npm`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it is not working.
What am I missing?

Comment: do you use some sort of build system? if not, installing a file using npm doesn't magically add it to a web page

Comment: What are you using node for? Are you using express to serve the site?

Comment: I assume the `var makerjs..` code is inside your `index.js` - if you put a `console.log('I am here:', makerjs);` on the next line and open the web development console then refresh the page - what does it print to it?

Comment: @ariel oh, I was misunderstanding with usage of node. So, when I use node, I am using with something else like server! Thank you :)

Comment: @Jaromanda Thank you! I was misunderstanding. Now I got it :)